# Compilation fails with texlive 2020

Tags: compilation-error, texlive-2020

When trying to compile the following MWE using pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Test Test
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
jbroedel@t450s:~/Dropbox/LatexTest$ pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name:
```

The file l3backend-pdfmode.def is not present. I am using the Debian packages of TexLive, which does now by default use some parts of l3backend:

```
ii  texlive-base   2020.20200925-1 all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
```

Did somebody experience a similar problem? If this turns out not to be my fault, I will file a bug report, however, would be happy for a workaround solution.

Comment: Is `l3backend` package installed?

Comment: `l3backend` is by now part of `texlive-latex-base`. So, yes, it is installed. There is no extra package `l3backend` any more, as far as I could find out.

Comment: The MWE works in my machine with texlive 2020. Are you using two different versions of `texlive` ? The [`l3backend`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3backend?lang=en) package is available on CTAN.

Comment: something got out of sync. You seem to have a new l3backend version (where pdfmode has been splitted into pdftex and luatex) and an older format/expl3 which still looks for pdfmode. Try to recreate the formats.

Comment: I recreatet the formats several times using Debians reconfigure mechanism. No improvement. I can see that I do have a newer version as the folder /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend does contain the two splitted .def files. I suppose Debian TexLive maintainers have packaged nonmatching versions - could this be the reason?

Comment: check if you have more than one format lurking around (`kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: `kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` delivers just one line, which reads `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: @Tanvir: I meant Debian packages as opposed to Tex packages on CTAN. I believe the problem is in the (Distribution) packaging. Which precise texlive 2020 version are you using and - if not compiled yourself - from which distribution?

Comment: and when you update the format this file is updated?

Comment: Probably I do not understand the mechanism completely: when the update mechanism builds the formats, it writes out `Building all formats....Done`. However, I have no idea, what this depends on, what formats it builds and where templates for the formats are located. Is there a place I can read about this mechanism?

Comment: @jbroedel The texlive version I am using is `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)`. This is the same as the one you are using, except they are not Debian packages.

Comment: Check the dates of the file, then you know if it new.

Comment: I checked and yes, the .fmt files are all updated.

Comment: @Tanvir: this supports the idea of some outdated Texlive component in one of the Debian packages. In particular, there is the (Debian-)package texlive-binaries, which is 2020.20200327. Is the information about the splitting into pdftex and luatex contained/coded in the pdflatex binary?

Comment: It seems that there are two Debian packages providing expl3: texlive-latex-base and texlive-latex-recommended. There is possibly a wrong version packaged - once I have found out, I will report here.

Answer (score 1):

Now pdflatex from TexLive runs flawless with the Debian TexLive packages.

The problem was the (not systemwide) folder `~/texlive2020` containing an old .fmt file. Following the usual latex strategy, this would be used preferrably over the newly generated systemwide format files from installing a new TeXLive version. Why this version of pdflatex.fmt in a subfolder of my home folder has not been found by `kpsewhich` (see comments on my question) is not clear to me, but can for sure be explained.

Punchline: the old installation was not completely removed for all users, and interfered with the new (and fresh) installation.